# Proof of Hilbert's Basis Theorem: won't $\deg (f_{i})$ be a strictly decreasing sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Say we have an ideal $I\subset R[X]$. We select a set of polynomials $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},\dots$ such that $f_{i+1}$ has minimal degree in $I\setminus (f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},\dots f_{i})$.

Can't $\deg (f_{i})$ be a strictly decreasing sequence?

For example, let the ideal $I\setminus (f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},\dots f_{i})$ contain polynomials of degree $2$ or greater. Say it contains the polynomials $x^2+2$ and $(x^2+2)^2+(x+1)$. Then $f_{i+1}=x^2+2$ and $f_{i+2}=x+1$!

Motivation: In [this](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Hilbert_s_basis_theorem.html) proof of Hilbet's Basis Theorem, we have constructed a polynomial $g=u_{1}f_{1}x^{n_{1}}+\dots u_{n}f_{n}x^{n_{N}}$, where $n_{i}=\deg (f_{N+1})-\deg(f_{i})$. I feel that then $n_{i}$ shoud be negative; and as $x$ raised to negative powers is not defined in $R[X]$, I'm having trouble understanding how $g=u_{1}f_{1}x^{n_{1}}+\dots u_{n}f_{n}x^{n_{N}}$ has been defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If $\deg f_{i+1}<\deg f_i$, then you would have chosen $f_{i+1}$ in place of $f_i$ in the previous step.

---

Going through the example in the OP.

Assume that the polynomials $p_1=(x^2+2)$ and $p_2=(x^2+2)^2+(x+1)$ belong to the ideal $I$, but do not belong to the smaller ideal $J_{i-1}=(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_{i-1})$ generated by the polynomials $f_i$ picked earlier. The polynomial
$p_3=x+1=p_2-p_1^2$ belongs to the ideal $I$. There are two possibilities.

**I)** If $p_3$ does not belong to the ideal $J_{i-1}$, then we will not be allowed to pick $f_i=p_1$, because $p_3$ has a lower degree and does not belong to the ideal $J_{i-1}$ either.

**II)** If $p_3$ belongs to the ideal $J_{i-1}$, then it will never be picked. Not now, not in the future.

So the scenario that we might pick $p_1$ in this round, and $p_3$ in the next is impossible.

Comment: Neither $f_i$ nor $f_{i+1}$ was in the ideal $(f_1,\ldots,f_{i-1})$, so... Or yet in other words, the pool of polynomials you can select the next one from SHRINKS all the time.

Comment: Could you kindly explain how could we have chosen $(x+1)$ before choosing $x^2+1$ in the example that I have given? I suppose I'm still a little confused.

Comment: Oh god. I suppose $(x+1)$ is anyway part of the ideal as $(x^2 +1)^2 + (x+1)-(x^2+1)(x^2+1)=(x+1)$. I really don't know what's happening to me I'm asking the stupidest of questions. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @Ayush: Don't worry about it. Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, $\deg(f_i)$ is a sequence of *natural numbers* (choose your own convention on what the degree of $0$ is here). Can you envision a strictly decreasing sequence of positive integers?

Comment: No. But that is the point! The essence of the proof is that there is no such infinite decreasing sequence of positive integers, and hence the ring $R[X]$ is neotherian.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan exactly, our supposition leads to a contradiction. it is a very nonconstructive proof (big names might even call it theology). if explicitness (err, the SFW kind) is what you seek, i recommend reading about Gröbner bases